# Selenium file upload for Angular form without direct input

Tags: java, angular, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

I have an Angular form where I should upload a file. Normally I would just use the `.sendKey(filePath)` method to set the input field's value, but in this case, it is not possible.

Here is the code of the form:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-container">
        <div class="file-input-list">
            <!---->
        </div>
        <input readonly="" type="text" class="form-control file-name-input" id="ec5e0202-5022-4df3-9f9b-2e4f1b0fc994" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-form-control"> Select file </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have a read-only text field (with a randomly generated ID to make things easy), and a sole button that launches the file browser window. If I select a file from that window, it will appear as a `chip` in the `file-input-list`.

I tried using `driver().switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(filePath);` but it is unable to set the filePath in the apperaring window.

I also looked for a hidden `file` type `input field`, but there isn't any.

Is there any way to somehow automate the file selection, or forcibly add the file to the `file-input-list`?

Comment: When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!